# access a tag by class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I create some tags by jQuery, and define a class name for that like bellow:

```
 $('#tr').html('<select class="optcode">
                 <option>select code</option>
                 <option>select code</option>'
              </select>);
```

in other place I want too access `<select>` by class name by code bellow but it does't work how can I solve that:

```
   $('.optcode').change(function(){
    alert('something');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a [**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):-

```
$('#tr').on('change', '.optcode', function(){
    alert('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The change function isn't binding to the elements because they don't exist in the DOM at the time the code is being executed.  You can use a function to add the elements to the DOM and the binding at the same time.

Something like this would work:

```
function doStuff() {

    $('#tr').html('<select class="optcode"><option>select code</option><option>select code</option></select>');

    $('.optcode').change(function(){
        alert('something');
    })

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doStuff();

})
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsvnhhn7/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$('#tr').html('<select class="optcode">
                 <option>select code</option>
                 <option>select code</option>'
              </select>);
```

TO

```
$('#tr').html('<select class="optcode"><option>select code</option><option>select code</option></select>');
```

see demo

```js
$('#tr').html('<select class="optcode"><option>select code</option><option>select code</option></select>');

 $('.optcode').change(function(){
    alert('something');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tr"></div>
```